# PyroCMS helper documentation

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper, pyrocms

I'm working on a PyroCMS project, but having problems due to the lack of complete documentation. Does anyone know where I can find a list of core helpers, such as `{pyro:navigation:links}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I only pushed those changes live yesterday, I am building the documentation for this as we speak!

**Tags**

```
{pyro:settings:site_name}
{pyro:settings:site_slogan} - or any other setting
{pyro:variables:foo}
```

**Plugins**

```
{pyro:navigation:links group="header"}

{pyro:session:data name="foo"}
{pyro:session:flash name="foo"}

{pyro:session:messages}
{pyro:session:messages success="success-box" notice="notice-box" error="error-box"}

{pyro:template:title}
{pyro:template:metadata}
{pyro:template:body}
{pyro:template:partial name="sidebar"}

{pyro:theme:path} - produces /path/to/addons/theme/xxx/
{pyro:theme:partial name="header"}
{pyro:theme:css file="style.css"}
{pyro:theme:js file="jquery.js"}
{pyro:theme:image file="logo.gif"}

{pyro:pages:url id="2"}

{pyro:url:current} - outputs http://example.com/the/current/url
{pyro:url:base} - outputs http://example.com/
{pyro:url:segments segment="2" default="something"}

{pyro:helper:lang line="foo"}
{pyro:helper:date format="d/m/Y"}

{pyro:pages:children id="2"}
    {title}
{/pyro:pages:children}

{pyro:news:posts limit="5"}
    &lt;h2>{title}&lt;/h2>
    {body}
{/pyro:news:posts}

{pyro:widgets:area slug="sidebar"}
{pyro:widgets:instance id="8"}
```

That's not a complete list as like I said, I am currently writing it!

It will be here when it's done: [PyroCMS Tag Reference](http://pyrocms.com/docs/tag-reference)

Answer (score 0):

We now have a pretty sweet Tag Reference:

http://pyrocms.com/docs/tag-reference

Answer (score 0):

The docs have moved.

http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/modules-and-tags

Also, a lot of the tags have changed to, so the navigation links would be something like:

```
{{ navigation:links group="header" }}
```